# What is the best practise for column based language on eloquent?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

Think about that, you have got an tables which has got an **one to one** and **one to many** relations with each others. You have got an language column for an each translation of row which provides language as an '**en**', '**dk**', '**fr**', '**it**' etc. I can get an default language with that kind of format on my controller. You can get those languages via `where()` query with Eloquent. Unfortunately, it not best practise. Because of the relations. It's too bad solution to write same query for the each relation. so my question is, what is the best practise for that kind of flexible databases to filtering as an current language?

**edit:**

I am sharing my table structure on the following segment:
[image]

Comment: Well post the table structures and explain what you're trying to achieve, cause _"You have a table with some relations"_ is not very explicit. You say it's not good practice to use a `where` condition because of the relations. Who says it's not good practice? It's not good practice based on what? We have no idea what your tables look like, so that might as well be a good approach, but we can't guess what's the best solution based on just a few sentences with no clear context.

Comment: I shared my table structure. you can review from the image...

Comment: Are those posts and tags, translations of one another? If so, it would mean that if you have a post in English and add a translation of that post in, let's say German, then there two posts will have two separate IDs, which means there's no way for you to determine if post B is the German translation of post A. The same applies for tags. Is this the desired behaviour? Are all post entries unique regardless of language with no translation relation whatsoever?

Comment: @Bogdan yes, exactly the same what you understood.

Comment: That sounds like having two distinct content sets (since I doubt you'll pair an English post with a German tag) so it might as well be two websites. So I have to ask, wouldn't it make more sense to have different databases for each language, rather than cramming different language entries into the same table and then adding complexity to query language specific entries according to locale. It's way easier to set the database connection based on locale and use that across the whole app. Is there anything that would prevent you from using this approach?

Comment: @Bogdan Yeah, you are right but it's not valid for my case. Because, I have got an users table and users choices their own language from database. It's not making sense to change database when user update their own language.